# bcrypt.checkpw returns TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking

Tags: python, bcrypt

I am calling `bcrypt.checkpw` to check unencrypted password matches with hashed password stored in the credential database, but receive

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking

How should I resolve this issue? Any suggestion?
I installed `python 2.7.6`, and `bcrypt 3.1.1`

I have the following code:

```
def check_password(password, hashed_password)
    if not bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed_password):
        raise InvalidCredentials("403 Forbidden")
    else:
        return true
```

And receive the following error:

> File "/home/qt/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/**init**.py", line 100, in checkpw
>   raise TypeError("Unicoed-objects must be encoded before checking")
>   TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking

I looked into `bcrypt/__init__.py`, but I'm not sure why

```
def checkpw(password, hashed_password):    
    if (isinstance(password, six.text_type) or            
        isinstance(hashed_password, six.text_type)):        
    raise TypeError("Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking")
```

Answer (score 36):

I make the assumption that you use Python 3. With Python 3, strings are, by default, unicode strings.

If you call the `bcrypt.checkpw()` function with unicode values:

```
import bcrypt

password = "seCr3t"  # unicode string
hashed_password = "hashed_seCr3t"  # unicode string

bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed_password)
```

You'll get this exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking
```

The reason is simple: cryptographic functions only work on bytes strings (or arrays in fact).

You *password* and *hashed_password* must be both bytes strings.

If you use the `bcrypt.hashpw()` function, your *hashed_password* must be a bytes string, and I think the problem is for the *password* value. This *password* must come from a HTML form of something similar. To use the `bcrypt.checkpw()` function, you must first encode the string value using the same encoding you use to encrypt the *password* with the `bcrypt.hashpw()` function. Usually, we choose 'utf8' encoding.

For instance (Python 2 & 3):

```
import bcrypt

# at creation first:
password = u"seCr3t"
hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())

# first attempt:
password = u"seCrEt"
bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), hashed_password)
# -> False

# second attempt:
password = u"seCr3t"
bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), hashed_password)
# -> True
```

See simple usage on [Gihub page](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/#usage)

Comment: Thanks Laurent for quick response and clear code example !   I am using python 2.7.6.  I tried your suggestion and it works without error.  I assume that strings, by default, unicode strings with python 2.7.6 as well.

Comment: No, Python 2 use bytes strings by default. If you want unicode strings, you need to use the "u" prefix like this: `u"foo"`, or convert the bytes string to unicode using `decode()` method. The unicode strings should come from your HTML form or similar input : this is the classic (and expected) behaviour.

Comment: I changed the examle to be Python 2 & 3 compatible

Comment: Hmm..So with Python 2, my original codes should work because both password and hashed password are in bytes string.   why did I get exception in that case then?

password = "seCr3t"  # bytes strings
hashed_password = "hashed_seCr3t"  # bytes string
bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed_password)

Comment: @user7153744: the original exception message is clear: you have at least one Unicode value (that must be encoded).

Comment: I tried it on Python 2.7.10. Works on my local but when I deployed to heroku, it keeps throwing the error

Comment: Do you need more explanation? If not, I suggest you to upvote and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471) my answer.

Answer (score 14):

Something you could do like this

```
bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), hashed_password)
```

simple does it

Comment: Nowadays this throws the error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: this should work: bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), hashed_password). Will update the answer

Answer (score 9):

i use something like that

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    login = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)

    @staticmethod
    def make_password_hash(password):
        hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password=password.encode('utf-8'), salt=bcrypt.gensalt())
        return hash.decode('utf-8')

    def is_password_valid(self, password):
        return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), self.password.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: This worked for me. I must decode the hashed password before store in db and encode it again before check with new password... Thank!

Comment: This saves my day! any reason why we should decode before store in DB?

Answer (score 0):

Using that like e.g. and see the comments below the code:

```
import bcrypt

def comparacaoSenha(passw, hash):
    if bcrypt.checkpw(passw, hash):
        print("It Matches!")
    else:
            print("It Does not Match")

password = "super secret password".encode('utf-8')
password2 = "another password".encode('utf-8')

hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
heashed2 = bcrypt.hashpw(password2, bcrypt.gensalt())

print("Teste 1: ")
print("-----------------------------")
print("PASSWORD: ", password)
print("HASHED PW: ", hashed)
comparacaoSenha(password, hashed)
print("-----------------------------")

print("Teste 2: ")
print("-----------------------------")
print("PASSWORD: ", password2)
print("HASHED PW: ", heashed2)
comparacaoSenha(password2, heashed2)
print("-----------------------------")

# Things to remember:
# always use the encode('utf-8') or put a prefix 'b'' just before the strings
# EX: newPass = b"OTHER PASSWORD" // or newPass="OTHER PASSWORD".encode('utf-8')
#
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and here is the solution
You have to decode after encoding before checking
**hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode('utf-8')**

**if user and bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), user.password.encode('utf-8')):**