# Bcrypt Encoding Error

Tags: python-3.x, bcrypt

I'm creating a flask-app and using wtforms. I have password stored in my database that is created from a form using the following:

```
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(form.password.data.encode('utf-8'), salt)
```

Now I want to check the password using:

```
    if bcrypt.checkpw(form.password.data.encode('utf8'), password_from_db):
```

When I do this the following error arises:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking
```

Not sure exactly what is causing this or how to resolve. It is something to do with the form and the data type though as I can follow standard python examples.

Many thanks

**EDIT**
I've checked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577867/bcrypt-checkpw-returns-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-checkin) but it didn't resolve my query. My query is using data from forms. I'm using the same method as in the answer but am still receiving the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bcrypt.checkpw returns TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577867/bcrypt-checkpw-returns-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-checkin)

Comment: I looked at that before asking the question. It was useful but didn't resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(form.password.data.encode('utf-8'), salt).decode('utf-8')

# While checking:
password_hashed=bcrypt.hashpw(form.password.data.encode('utf8'), password_from_db.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

if password_hashed == password_from_db:
     print('User succesfully logged in')
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? Code-only answers are discouraged as they don't provide as great of opportunity for learning.

When writing code blocks, you should use proper syntax highlighting to make your answer easier to read. For more information on using the editor, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).