# TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking

Tags: python

I am comparing a hashed password (which is from .txt file) with what data the login page receives (**using bcrypt**).

I have done that, but I know I have done something wrong because i have a typerror. Im not sure what I have done wrong and was wondering if one of you would spot it?

**Code Snippet**

```
...

        supplied_username = pg.e1.get() # Gets content of a tkinter entry box
        supplied_password = pg.e2.get() ^

        supplied_username.encode('utf-8') #encoding 
        supplied_password.encode('utf-8') ^

        if bcrypt.checkpw(supplied_username, 
        hashed_username) and bcrypt.checkpw(supplied_password, hashed_password) == True:
        
        #Do stuff such as login
```

**Error Message:**

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking

Which i did do, but I guess i did it wrong because it doesnt work. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What orlp stated should work (modulo what is obviously a typo in the second line). This is also possibly a duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577867/bcrypt-checkpw-returns-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-checkin).

Answer (score 1):

`.encode` does not change the original string, it returns a copy of the string encoded in the specified encoding.

I'd suggest:

```
valid_username = bcrypt.checkpw(supplied_username.encode('utf-8'), hashed_username)
valid_password = bcrypt.checkpw(supplied_password.encode('utf-8'), hashed_password)
if valid_username and valid_password:
    ...
```

At least, that's the modification of your current code to 'make it work'. I don't mean to imply that I suggest any particular security scheme.

Comment: Sorry i'm still getting the original type error unfortunately.