# Facing Issue with BCRYPT Module In Python

Tags: python, encryption, bcrypt

This is for my school project.
I made a function to encrypt functions using bcrypt in python. Now the encryption is fine and I can store it. But it shows error while checking the hashed code.

```
    def decrypt(password, hashed):
        password=password.encode('utf-8')
        return bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed)
```

This is the function. Here the 'password' is the input by user and 'hashed' variable I am calling from the database.

This is the error I am getting

[image]

what do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bcrypt.checkpw returns TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577867/bcrypt-checkpw-returns-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-checkin)

Comment: I understood part of the problem. The 'hashed' variable was a string but when i decode and encode it, its still not working

Comment: You may have used an encoding regarding `hashed` that corrupts the data (e.g. UTF-8). Post the relevant code. If the data should be stored as string, you should use a binary-to-text encoding like Base64. Before storing, Base64 encode the data, after loading and before passing it to `checkpw()`, Base64 decode it. Or alternatively store the data in binary.